# User interface of Custom module in Kentico CMS issues

Tags: user-interface, module, kentico

I added a user interface in a custom module. To use the kentico FCKEditor editable region I added the CMSEditableRegion  and CMSPortalManager.  When I click on the page link from the Page tab, it works just fine as expected. But when I click on the link from the design tab it give error (see the pic).[image]

[image]

Also when I move another page in the content tree my module does not update its content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an object's value without initializing it.

Comment: I am using cmsportalmanager, if I remove it then there is no error.

Comment: Do you have the codes for cmsportalmanager, some object is not being initialized. Are you missing some parameter?

Comment: No, I dont have. the weird thing is page tab may have something that design tab do not have. And when I changed the cmsportalmanager to cmspagemanager there is no error again, but the editable text is not visible.

Comment: If you are not missing any parameter in the design tab, then this is clearly an exception thrown by the cmsportalmanager.

Comment: If you can, use CMSPortalManager. CMSPageManager will sooner or later become obsolete. Make sure CMSPageManager is in correct viewmode. Try adding query string parameter 'viewmode' to your url. Values can be found in ViewModeEnum (e.g. 3 = edit (page), 6 = design, 0 = livesite).